# How to stay in browser() mode even after encountering an error?

Tags: r, debugging

To debug, I usually insert `browser()` slightly above the point where I suspect the error occurs. Then I'll step through the code (with `n`) to understand what's going on.

Upon running the line that causes the error, RStudio will exit the `browser()` mode. Is there a way to stay in the `browser()` mode?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `options(error = recover)`. Relevant help file is [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/recover.html).